# ksoap2 connection timeout

Tags: c#, java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I am trying to call a .net web service from an android emulator but I am getting connection timeout exception.

Before I tried to call my webService I called the http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx without problems.

So I am assuming that either I have something wrong in my .net webService either in android application.

the .net is

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Pros : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Product> Get(int pageIndex,int pageSize) {
        var efUnitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork();
        var productsRepos = new ProductRepository(new EFRepository<Product>(), efUnitOfWork);
        return (List<Product>)productsRepos.GetByPage(pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

and the java is

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Get";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.0.2:2807/webservices/webService.asmx";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("pageIndex", "0");
        request.addProperty("pageSize", "10");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

        String resultData=result.getProperty(0).toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the timeout for the call like this:

```
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to increase the timeout as mentioned but more importantly you have to move your call into a background thread. Use AsyncTask.

Also as discussed in the comment there is a blog post linked in the ksoap2-android wiki that explains the connection stuff in detail. You can NOT use localhost or equivalent since that is on the device but your service runs on a server.. now that I look at the code again .. 10.0.0.2 will not work most likely.

Do an ifconfig/ipconfig on the server and use that IP address. I bet it will work then.

Comment: I increased the the timeout and I moved the call in an AsyncTask but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: can you actually connect to the service from the device e.g. on the browser?

Comment: no I can't connect. But I uploaded the .net application in a production server and it works. Something goes wrong with localhost.